# Problems on running MyFaces project with Tomcat in Windows (java.lang.LinkageError)

Tags: tomcat, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, myfaces

I'm facing this problem that I cant understand the error. This projects runs ok on Mac, but on Windows is happening this:

```
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.addELResolver(Ljavax/el/ELResolver;)V" the class loader (instance of com/springsource/insight/collection/tcserver/ltw/TomcatWeavingInsightClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/myfaces/webapp/Jsp21FacesInitializer, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type javax/el/ELResolver used in the signature
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.configureResolverForJSP(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:129)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:77)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:140)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
08/05/2012 10:32:48 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

I use the same version of Eclipse SpringSource Tool Suite in both platforms.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you disable Spring Insight for the server seeing this issue?

Comment: I tried it with enabled and disabled. No success..

Comment: So I moved to Tomcat 7. No changes at source code and eclipse project. It's working. I think may be my STS installation got corrupt. I'll gonna close this question.

Answer (score 0):

So I moved to Tomcat 7. No changes at source code and Eclipse Project. It's working.

I think, maybe, my STS installation got corrupt. I'll gonna close this question.